# Google app engine compatibility with Spring framework

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I have started developing a web app using google app engine and Spring 4. But now i have understood that Spring 4 does't fully support with Google app engine.
Now i need the latest version of Spring framework that fully support with google app engine.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: I read this answers also. But i couldn't get suitable answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067187/spring-framework-support-with-google-app-engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the list of Spring supported modules and versions in this 
[link](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava) :

**Spring MVC**
Version  2.5.6
Status   COMPATIBLE

**Spring ORM**
Version  2.5.6
Status   COMPATIBLE

**Spring Security**
Version(s)   ?
Status   SEMI-COMPATIBLE
To work around a ClassNotFoundException, you can use a re-compiled version of the library which adds a StringInsensitiveComparator class .

For more details check out this [link](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava).
Hope it helped, Good luck

Comment: It's a good practice to copy the key elements of the answer behind the link into your answer. It makes it easier to use, and also it will remain valid even after the link you provided dies.

Comment: I think the link is outdated. I use web/MVC 3.2.4 & security 3.1.4 without any issues. You write "full support", but one rarely use all the modules at once.

Comment: This answer is based on a 2 year before link.Please be updated